# Запрос на поиск выдает пустой результат MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с постами, в которой во всех постах автор saluteismyname, я пишу запрос на выборку всех постов, где автор LIKE saluteismyname, и мне выдает пустой результат. Что я делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без кавычек в имени колонки попробуйте

Comment: Симон прав.. кавычки не те) + сомнительно вообще использование LIKE в данном случае) + в тории `author = Integer` с ID на users

Comment: дабы дополнить первый коммент и чтобы автору стало ясно в чем суть - вы один строковый литерал с помощью like спраниваете с другим строковым литералом. а-ля `WHERE 'foo' like '%bar%'`, понятное дело что вернет это false, и к именам столбцов отношения не имеет.

Comment: Понял))) Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поле author должно быть без кавычек:

```
select * from posts where author like '%saluteismyname%'
```

Если используете кавычки, MySQL считает что вы используете зарезервированное слово или спецсимволы

Comment: для экранирования зарезервированных слов используются обратные кавычки. Обычные - для определения строковый литералов. В некоторых случаях их можно использовать как алиас в селекте, например.